# active_scaffold hangs on infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, infinite-loop, activescaffold

I'm trying to use `active scaffold`(3.0.26) in my Rails (3.0, ruby 1.8.7) project. I've added a simple tender to my page:

```
<%= render :active_scaffold => 'users', :constraints => {:gender => "male"}%>
```

When I enter that page, application starts an infinite loop. consumes more and more resources and the only solution is to `kill -9` the server process. It feels like a basic mistake, but I don't know, what I did wrong. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use Active Scaffold. It's a really old and buggy project. I would recommend the use of [rails_admin](http://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) instead.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The things is that I'm not looking for an admin panel, but plugin for tables with advanced features (sort, find, etc). I want to be able to easily embed these 'super-tables' in any place of my application.

Comment: Similar problem occurs [when I use ActiveAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9749909/580346), so I believe it wasn't a bug in the Active Support.